# Border design with two colors in a HTML file

Tags: html, css

I want a straight line having two colors and a slant line in between. I need a result like this:

> [image]

Comment: _I need a result like this..._ Sorry but SO doesn't work this way - **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts!

Comment: What you tried so far to achieve it?

Comment: please add more content eg: what you had done

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to use the border attribute so badly. You can use [`SVG`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)[`attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute)[`d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) to do so:

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.stripdiag {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><path d='M0 97 L100 97 L100 100 L0 100 L0 97Z' fill='blue' /><path d='M61 97 L100 97 L100 100 L61 100 L61 97Z' fill='red' /><path d='M60 100 L61 100 L70 1 L69 0 L60 100Z' fill='white' /></svg>");
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripdiag"></div>
```

Important stuff to go by:

> **M** <sub>x,y</sub>  Move to the absolute coordinates x,y
>
> **m** <sub>x,y</sub>  Move to the right x and down y (or left and up if negative values)
>
> **L** <sub>x,y</sub>  Draw a straight line to the absolute coordinates x,y
>
> **l** <sub>x,y</sub>  Draw a straight line to a point that is relatively right x and down y (or left and up if negative values)
>
> **H** <sub>x</sub>    Draw a line horizontally to the exact coordinate x
>
> **h** <sub>x</sub>    Draw a line horizontally relatively to the right x (or to the left if a negative value)
>
> **V** <sub>y</sub>    Draw a line vertically to the exact coordinate y
>
> **v** <sub>y</sub>    Draw a line vertically relatively down y (or up if a negative value)
>
> **Z** or **z**    Close the current subpath by connecting the last point of the path with its initial point. If the two points are at different coordinates, a straight line is drawn between those two points.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
//HTML
<div class="stripebar"></div>

//CSS
.stripebar{
    height: 5px; //or whatever height you want your div to be
    border-top: 5px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, red 32%, white 32.5%, white 33%, 
    white 33.5%, blue 34%) 5;
}
```

Check out an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/we52h369/2/

Obviously you'll have to play with the values depending on where your border is (top or bottom), also depending on the width of your div, you may have to change the gradient stop points. As you can see, to get the angle you wanted I had to rotate the gradient by -45 degrees - as a result of this, all the stop points are in reverse order. I'm sure there's a better way, but it's late and i'm tired and this seems to work for now. The last value of the border image gradient (after the brackets) changes the pitch of the angle - higher value = steeper pitch. Play around with all of them and i'm sure you can get it to what you need. Just remember - the magic at work here is the border-image property. Look into that further if you still need help making it work.

Cheers